# Python - How do I update a dictionary with a loop that has one key and two values?

Tags: python

I'm doing an exercise but I'm a bit stuck. I need to parse through a text file that has ERROR or INFO messages attached to a username.
I then need to create a dictionary where I have the username as the key and one value being the amount of ERROR messages, and the other value being the amount of INFO messages.
I will then put that in a CSV file where I need the header for the key to be "Username" and the other two headers be "ERROR" and "INFO"

Basically the finished result needs to look like this:

[image]

The part I'm stuck at is the first bit where I need to update a dictionary with the username as key and the amount of messages as values.

This is the code I have so far where I've only been able to figure out how to grab the amount of messages for the username but they're in two separate dictionaries:

```
import re
import csv
from collections import Counter

test_list = []
test_list2 = []


with open(r"syslog.txt", "r") as log:
  for i in log:
    if re.findall("ERROR.*", i):
      test_list.append(re.findall("ticky:.*ERROR [\w '].*\(([\w\.]*).*$", i))
    elif re.findall("INFO.*", i):
      test_list2.append(re.findall("ticky:.*INFO [\w '].*\(([\w\.]*).*$", i))

flattened = [val for sublist in test_list for val in sublist]
test_dict = Counter(flattened)
print(test_dict)

flattened2 = [val for sublist in test_list2 for val in sublist]
test_dict2 = Counter(flattened2)
print(test_dict2)
```

And here's a few lines from the syslog.txt:

```
Jan 31 05:18:45 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (sri)
Jan 31 05:23:14 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#1097] (breee)
Jan 31 05:35:00 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (nonummy)
Jan 31 05:45:30 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#7115] (noel)
Jan 31 05:51:30 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR The ticket was modified while updating (flavia)
```

So now I need to figure out a way to get these values in the same dictionary while keeping the key. Preferably I want to do it without merging the two dictionaries and instead just create one dictionary from the start.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's `syslog.txt`? Please show a small, representative snippet. If you're able to successfully parse this, you could just show what your data structures are in memory. It's hard to help without a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: You do understand that a dictionary only has one value per key, yes? So you've already anticipated the need to create single values that encode both the info-count and error-count information? Such as, say, a tuple or list?

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry about that! I added a few lines from it now to make it more clear. Thanks!

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That makes sense! So would a dictionary with the key being the username and the value being a list with the two different message amounts work best then? Since lists are mutable? Thank you!

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not clear where the values for the INFO and ERROR columns come from. How are you getting cell values like `5` or `6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You could use a dictionary in order to store other two dictionaries

```
info = dict()
error = dict()
username = {'info': info, 'error': error}
users = {'username': username}
```

How to **get** values?

```
for user in users:
    print(user['info'])
    print(user['error'])
```

---

### You could create a user object

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, username, info, error):
        self.username = username
        self.info = info
        self.error = error
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Using dictionaries in dictionary makes a lot of sense. I'm just completely lost on how to implement that in my script. I can't seem to figure out how to get the username as key and the message amounts as values in the nested dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for that! I think I actually made sense of it now and I shouldn't have to create the user object. Now I just need to figure out how to create the csv using the keys as headers and sort it. Thanks again!